# Image save and retrieve as byte array in postgres using java

Tags: java, postgresql

Please help me and give me a example to save images as byte array and retrieve them. I am using Java and postgre sql is the database I am use.\

```
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
          imageArray[index] =  e.target.result;
          FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
      }
    });
```

this use to get the image..

```
imageByte1 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Image);
```

then retrive through,

```
new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(item.getImage1())
```

this is use to convert. But out put is different from the what I save.

Comment: This is not a "gimme code" website. If you write some code and encounter a problem you cannot solve or figure out then you can ask a specific question about that.

Comment: Firstly please add some of your code to show what you have already tried, then we can help you debug your issues. Here is a guide how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: done. I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

You're storing binary as base64 in the DB, by the looks. Using a pair of mismatched input and output routines, one of which is not even public API (`com.sun.` space).

Please don't.

Use JDBC's support for blobs with `java.sql.Types.BLOB`, via `java.sql.PreparedStatement` and bind parameters. Please. The corresponding PostgreSQL data type for the column should be `bytea`.

Answer (score 0):

In PostGres the data type for byte array (byte []) is **bytea** . So use the data type for create the column.

**Saving:**

```
File file = new File("myimage.gif");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO images VALUES (?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, file.getName());
ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int)file.length());
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
fis.close();
```

**Retrive:**

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT img FROM images WHERE imgname = ?");
ps.setString(1, "myimage.gif");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    byte[] imgBytes = rs.getBytes(1); OR  byte []out = (byte[])(rs.getObject(1));
    // use the data in some way here
}
rs.close();
ps.close();
```

Help: [Storing Binary Data](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/binary-data.html)